# How to run mypy in Spyder?

Tags: spyder

I wish to use `mypy` with `Spyder` but when I issue the command `%mypy` the following error got detected:

```
error: Name "runcell" is not defined
```

I assume that `mypy` is correctly installed because when I run `%load_ext mypy_ipython` I get no error messages.
To reproduce the problem you can define an arbitrary working code-cell that uses `typing` functions in the `Spyder` editor and then run `%load_ext mypy_ipython` to load the module and then `%mypy` to execute it.